# How would I be able to make python always check for the time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time
import tkinter
import win10toast

toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M", t)
workout_times = ['']
workout_time = str(input('What time do you want your reminder to come(Format is Hour:Minute): '))
workout_times.append(workout_time)
while current_time == current_time:
    if current_time == workout_time:
       print(2)
       toaster.show_toast('Reminder', 'DO IT`', duration=10)
       break
```

How would I be able to make python always check for the time? Like for you to input a time, for python to constantly check for the time and when it comes for it to run the if stament.

Comment: It's not the best idea to let python monitor time, better to resolve it on OS level.

Comment: And how would I do that? Would I use os.time?

Comment: I mean that python script should just execute notification, scheduled start have to be done using job scheduler in OS (*cron* in Unix-like, *schtasks* in Windows).

Comment: You're importing tkinter, but the code doesn't seem to use tkinter. Are you wanting a solution that works in a tkinter app that calls `mainloop`?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, yet I do think it is worthy to answer the question and show a way for comparing between the current time and a target time (if you do decide to run such a python code, I guess you’d want to run this in the background by calling your python script with pythonw.exe via command line or script). So below is one simple option for monitoring the time and executing a task:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

sleep_period = 60
target_time = datetime(2020, 8, 10, 10, 33) # you can construct the numbers inside from user input
while True:
    delta = datetime.today()-target_time
    if delta.days == 0 and delta.seconds <= sleep_period:
        print('It is time to execute a function')
        break # or ask for another input…
    sleep(sleep_period)
```